# How can I format a color rectangle with caption and text inside it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to create this layout on HTML page using HTML5/CSS3/JS.
Please advise, how it can be achieved?

Colored rectangle should have some padding, caption should be aligned on the left, and decimal value should be aligned on center both vertically on horizontally. I've tried to achive this using tables, but how to do this using divs?

How I can scale font size for decimal value based on colored rectangle height&width?

[image]

Comment: Please post what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy to center with `flex-box`

```css
body {
  font: normal 1em/1 sans-serif;
}

.box {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #2db051;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 220px;
  position: relative;
  width: 460px;
}
.box:before {
  content: attr(data-caption);
  font-size: 18px;
  left: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  top: 20px;
}
.box strong {
  font-size: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" data-caption="caption">
  <strong>123</strong>
</div>
```

Flexbox needs to be prefixed before live (https://autoprefixer.github.io/).

Answer (score 1):

you can use a single div with some css:

```
<div class="cont" title="caption">123</div>

.cont
{ 
  position:relative;
  width:300px; 
  height:200px; 
  line-height:200px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:60px;
  color:#FFF;
  background-color:green;
}
.cont:before
{
  content:attr(title);
  font-size:18px;
  position:absolute;
  line-height:1em;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
  z-index:1;
}
```

you can play with it here: [example in codepen.io(which is how you should post questions next time - better to play with existing code)](http://codepen.io/avipinto/pen/JGLraK)

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

https://jsfiddle.net/3xrxz1oa/

HTML

```
<div id="container">123</div>
```

JS for calculate font size

```
var containter = document.getElementById("container");
containter.innerHtml = 'test'
var fontSize = parseInt(containter.clientHeight/2)+"px";
containter.style.fontSize = fontSize;
```

CSS style

```
#container {
    height:200px;
    width:90%;
    background-color:#1CB254;
    color: white;
    padding:5%;
    text-align: center;    
}

#container::before {
    content: "Caption";
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}
```

I calculated the font size based on height. You can do more complex calculation.